# Is it possible to use 2 server(same port number) i,e, expo and express in one project at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, expo, mern

I have researched and looked wherever I can about the question which I am about to ask so thats why you are seeing this question here. I am doing a react native mobile apps using MERN stack on expo cli, the problem here is that to run the project we run it through expo port number but if I wanted to use express framework I will need to have another server i.e express server so two different port number. Whenever I run the project only expo server started and the express server is not started unless I run it manually, but when I ran the express framework, while expo is running, both the server runs on 2 different port number so the project doesn't sync, meaning it is 2 different project now as it runs on different port number. What I want to know here is that -

1. is it possible to use Express in react native mobile apps?
2. If yes, how to use it? and
3. Is it possible to merge the port number into 1 and run on only 1 server?

Thank You so much..

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

**1**

If you want to run a server express in react native mobile apps then no.

You can run a react native mobile app on your smartphone and it will communicate with your express server by fetching request.

**3**

You can not merge the port number because a port is limited to one application in TCP communication. Running only one server require to merge the code from expo and express.

Comment: Is fetching request the CRUD operations in Express?

Comment: yes, this is the operations asked by your react native app

Comment: so then what shall I put in the portnumber i,e app.listen(portnumber)

Comment: You can use any free port number

Comment: okay so that means even if the port number is different it will do its task withuot any problem? I just have to expo start the project, thats what you are saying right

Comment: Yes, the port is only a door where messages can pass through and only one application can receive messages per door. You only have to be careful at which door you send your message. Just change the port where express listen, then you only have to change the port where you send your request from your application.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot,,  I was busy working on a problem  which does not  exist